# Using Fiddler: Inject cookie into all subsequent requests from initial request

Tags: http, cookies, fiddler

I have a batch of requests in Fiddler, the first is a login request and returns a valid cookie. The rest need to use this cookie, I know I can break and edit headers but is it possible to automatically script this behaviour? I'm pretty new to Fiddler but it looks powerful so I'm hoping this is possible, anyone know how or where to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manually add a header, use the `Filters` tab and use the `Request Headers` section.

To automatically add a header, click Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll to `OnBeforeResponse` and write code that stores the target cookie in a global variable declared just inside the `Handlers` function, e.g.

```
static var m_MyCookie: String;
```

Then, inside the `OnBeforeRequest` function, use that variable, e.g.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_MyCookie)) oSession.oRequest["Cookie"] = (m_MyCookie + ";" + oSession.oRequest["Cookie"] )
```

If you're only trying to add this header to specific requests, use, for instance, the `oSession.uriContains` function to determine whether the target URL is one that you want to have the cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the scripts were the key. There was only one thing I couldn't resolve: If the response cookie has two "Set-Cookie:" values I can only get the last value via oSession.oResponse["Set-Cookie"]. However, it shows both values in the inspector is it possible to get to each value or is it only the last "[Set-Cookie]" that is accessible?

Comment: When you first posted the original question, I discovered the bug you mention. It's fixed for the next version. :-)

Comment: Haha - fair enough :] I can work around this. Thanks for all the hard work and your continued efforts with Fiddler - it is a great app.